# What value put in System.Assert Methods To check the its work?

Tags: system

How To Check Different Assert Methods in this code?

```
public with sharing class AssertEx 
{

 public integer sum()

{
         integer a =10;

         integer b =20;

         integer c;

         c=a+b;

         system.debug('======'+c);

         //system.assert();

         //system.assertequals();

         //System.assertNotEquals();

         return c;

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to write the test code and assertions inside a test class/method, not in the actual class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should google articles before posting anything here.

Have you looked at this article?
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008x42IAA

Anyways, here are your asserts:

```
System.assert(c==10);
System.assertEquals(a,10);
System.assertNotEquals(b,10);
```

Comment: I declare this values are these right values?                              System.assertequals(30,c);                                             System.assertNotEquals(20,c);

Comment: Why don't you give them a try in your code? You will get a better understanding. And yes they are correct.

Comment: This should be `System.assertEquals(10, a);` and same for `NotEquals`.  expected, then actual.